# Website stuck into Infinite Loop

Tags: cookie, customer-session, magento1.9.2.3

I got a strange problem in my multiwebsite store. When a random user do login at frontend, the page keeps continuously and user doesn't get my account page and in after few minutes it shows memory limit exhausted error. Memory limit is already very high there 20000M.

after this problem, no other pages of website works as well and keep loading.

But Now as I clear site cookie and data from browser, it works fine for all other pages for site but as I try again to login with same username and password as I used before, it creates same problem.

So may be it is a cookie or session related issue since after clearing it site works fine.
But I don't know how to resolve it and where to amend it in site files.

if anyone has any idea please suggest me the possible ways to resolve it or ask me for any details.

Thanks